# Join fails - Definition must be in the form of a SELECT statement

Tags: sql

I am trying to join the `alt_id_view` to get the `client name` from `client_personal_view`. But it gives this error:

> Definition must be in the form of a `SELECT` statement.

Do you notice what is wrong here? the columns are all valid.

```
SELECT a.alternative_id_type_description, a.id_number, b.full_name 
FROM alt_id_view a 
INNER join client_personal_view b ON a.people_id = b.people_id
```

Comment: What database are you using (SQl server, mysql, postgres, oracle, etc..)? I don't see anything wrong with the query, but I also find nothing online about that particular error code.

Comment: I should have said sorry. I am using this beast called myevolv. It is sql based but I know nothing more. But the typical sql statements work.

Comment: Are you sure there's such a long column : `alternative_id_type_description` within that view ?

Comment: MyEvolv... I'm going to have to bow out of this one. That is a definite niche area. Not much documentation online either. Shame :(

Comment: I've no experience with myevolv, but a couple of suggestions if you haven't tried them. Try not using the table aliases (remove `a` and `b`, and use fully-qualified table names instead), or try using the old, less-friendly join syntax that uses table names separated by commas instead of `inner join`

Comment: yes it was the long name that was the problem.      select a.*, b.full_name from alt_id_view a 
inner join client_personal_view b
on a.people_id = b.people_id